# In accessibility mode, how to send an string to screen reader when user double tap on a button in react-native?

Tags: react-native, accessibility

Here, when someone tap on that button, VoiceOver or TalkBack will tell what is written in the accessibility label.

Now, I need a way to let the VoiceOver or Talkback speak that the button has been clicked by double-tapping.

I have attached a sample code below.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
accessible={true} 
accessibilityLabel="button for adding email address. Double tap to add alternative email" 
onPress={() => { this.addEmailField() }} >
<Text>Add email address</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Thank you very much for your efforts and time.

Comment: I wouldn't recomend doing this. If you have to explain to users what to do, it generally isn't a great user experience. 
I would suggest that what a user focuses a button is says "Add an alternative email address", that way they know when they click the button it will give them an option to do that.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right. But what I want actually is VoiceOver after clicking the button. Like when a user double clicks on a save button, voiceOver should say "Saved".

Comment: Oh in that case you could use an alert role https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_alert_role

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this

```
accessibilityLabel={this.props.clicked ? 'saved' : 'button for adding email address. Double tap to add alternative email'}
```